# What does [HYPOS] tag on logcat relate to in Samsung Galaxy S II?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, logging

I have Samsung Galaxy S II. When I check the logcat using Eclipse, I see an entry with tag `[HYPOS]`.

What is that? I am worried about my privacy.

Comment: Please provide more information. I'm not sure that anyone will be able to give you a reasonable answer based on the content of this post, currently. What are you doing when you see this "log tag"? Where are you seeing it? What is it exactly, an entry in the logcat "Tag" column?

Answer (score 2):

From:

- [Is GPS chip control affected by 'sensor aiding'? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917845/is-gps-chip-control-affected-by-sensor-aiding)
- [Suspected memory leak (in Sygic); how to interpret the Allocation Tracker - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866023/suspected-memory-leak-in-sygic-how-to-interpret-the-allocation-tracker)
- [Show on Map - cgeo Issue Tracker](https://github.com/cgeo/c-geo-opensource/issues/703)

All of these people are posting issues or logcats relating to the GPS on their phone, I would imagine yours is something similar if it's in a line like:

```
DEBUG/(2696): [HYPOS] NOMOVE Time 13114, PowerMode 2, GPSWeakSignal 19, GPSFixTime 0, Car 1, DOE 3
```

The fact it also says GPS in the logcat entry is a hint also.

Answer (score 0):

An app developer can use any word as log tag. The log tag 'HYPOS' can be from any good/bad app that you have installed in you phone.